# Get properties by @Value and put it into application.yml programmatically. Java with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, spring-bean

I use **Azure KeyVault** to store some values. I need to get this values (e.g. *mysql-uri* or *client-secret*) and create new properties in application.yml (and application-local.yml).
First of all, I tried to create Configuration-class with **@Bean** like getDataSource to create connection to database and I did it successfully, but I need to add other fields as well, such as 'oauth.client.secret'.

So I tried to get values and create 'properties' in main-class, but **@Value** couldn't be static and this solution throws **NPE**. I tried to create new Configuration-class and get properties from it and then pull it into `SpringApplicationBuilder`, but I need ApplicationContext (so `SpringApplication.run` will be called) to get an instance (bean) of this class with values...

I don't know what to do next, I'm stuck. Ready to rewrite and show any solution you need.

**UPDATE 1:**

```java
    @Value("${secret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DefaultApplication.class).properties(getProperties()).run(args);        
    }

    @NotNull
    private static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("oauth.client.secret", Objects.requireNonNull(clientSecret));

        return properties;
    }
```

clientSecret with error: *Non-static field 'clientSecret' cannot be referenced from a static context*.

Comment: Why do you need the configuration properties in a static / build context? Spring will automatically inject it into managed beans. May be you can show us the main class which is where the problem is?

Comment: @aksappy I added this code.

Comment: Thanks, can you use `SpringApplication.run` instead of the builder?

Comment: @aksappy, yes, but I'm not sure if I can add properties this way.

Comment: Spring automatically injects the application.properties/yaml config into any managed beans (classes annotated with Service, Configuration, Component etc). I am posting an example, to show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way of injecting properties. This uses a simpler convenience class `SpringApplication` instead of `SpringApplicationBuilder`.

**MainClass.java**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

The application.yaml will be automatically loaded into the context by Spring Boot (unless you have configured against it). Properties can be reused, redefined (using profiles) and system/env variables can be used as well.

**NOTE** Spring configurations are pretty flexible and powerful. Please read this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

**application.yaml**

```yaml
app:
  name: Demo
oauth:
  client:
    secret: ${app.name} // This will have "Demo"
env:
  path: ${SOME_ENV_VAR} // This will take SOME_ENV_VAR from env variable
```

**SomeService.java**

```java
@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Value("${app.name})
    private String appName;

    public void printAppName() {
        log.info(appName); // will log the appname
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you get value of this appName and recreate new propertie programmatically with key app.name.new (for example) and log it again?

Comment: Updated the answer. We can use app.name property and declare it as the value of a new key.

Comment: Oh my God! Wait, I need to try it!